# println not showing anything on screen Intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am running the following test from IntelliJ

```
fun testBooking() = runBlocking {
        val booking = getBookingForDateTime(defaultBookingTestDate, defaultBookingTestTime)
        val result = vendorPlugin.book(booking)
        println(result)
        assert(result.isSuccessful)
    }
```

I am expecting the println to print the result. But i don't see anything printed anything.
**I have tried changing the test settings from gradle to Intellij**
**Also tried to print a static string also.**
None of these dislayed anything on in **build, run or any window**

Comment: You should probably learn how to debug. Like does it even reach that line? You could try and see if a `println` at the start of the function does anything. Or try to figure out what is inside `result`

Comment: hey thanks for the response. I did tried printing at the start of function

Comment: Like Ivo says, Google how to "Debug..." rather than "Run..." Kotlin code within IntelliJ and put a breakpoint inside the block to see if it's being run at all. If it's not then you know that somehow runBlocking isn't being used correctly

Answer (score 1):

Hey bud I know this reponse is over a year old but in your IDE make sure you're actually calling the function somewhere so the system knows to run it. For example above your code block you could write:

testBooking()

Which should call your function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).